# Can IntelliJ 2020 extract a `Callable` lambda function into a newly created class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

Can IntelliJ 2020 take this code:

```java
Callable < Boolean > callable = ( ) -> {
    System.out.println( this.toString() );
    return Boolean.TRUE;
};
```

…and extract the two lines in the middle into a newly created class implementing `Callable`?

Comment: @Sweeper I mean 2020 — IntelliJ 2020.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't. I could not find a way to do it, at least.
I suppose you want to extract the lambda into a generic class with one method that contains the two lines of the lambda. If you only want this such that you are able to assign this lambda to a variable, you could also use one of the existing functional interfaces. `java.util.function.Supplier<T>` would be a good fit for this case.

```
Supplier<Boolean> callable = () -> {
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    return Boolean.TRUE;
};
```